# Git and WebScarab installation

Tags: git, github, webscarab

I need to install WebScarab but I do not know what does git and how can I instal it with git. can anyone explain me, how to install latest WebScarab from Git. Link: http://dawes.za.net/gitweb.cgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [main WebScara page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) mentions, you don't need Git to install WebScara:

> A ZIP containing an up to date build of the master branch of the [webscarab git tree](http://dawes.za.net/gitweb.cgi?p=webscarab.git) can be found [here](http://dawes.za.net/rogan/webscarab/#current).
>   This file is rebuilt whenever new commits are pushed to the repository, and will always be the most up to date build of WebScarab available.
>
> - Linux: `java -jar ./webscarab-selfcontained-[numbers].jar`
> - Windows: double-click the installer jar file ([complete installation instructions](http://www.acsac.org/2007/downloads/t5-webscarab-instructions.pdf))

In short, unless you want to develop/contribute to the code base of WebScara, you don't need Git.

Comment: This is not working at all. The first link doesn't have any zip file, and the second returns 503.
If you download the tarbal, there is no jar inside, and you have to built it your self.

Comment: @Guillermo true, yet those are the links still mentioned in https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project. I will investigate and see if new updated links can be found.

Answer (score 9):

The process to use git to checkout the source of WebScarab is as follows:

```
$ git clone git://dawes.za.net/webscarab.git
$ ant build
$ java -jar webscarab.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

git clone git://dawes.za.net/webscarab.git doesn't seem to work

try:

wget "http://dawes.za.net/gitweb.cgi?p=webscarab.git;a=snapshot;h=b148c63c06ac84ebdee12970929480a068d38422;sf=tgz"

rename file to:
 webscarab.tar.gz 
use:
 tar -xf webscarab.tar.gz

this is taking too long ... zzz

Answer (score -2):

For those that are unfamiliar with git and compiling java code (like myself), webscarab isn't worth the trouble with other tools like Fiddler out there.

http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What does Fiddler do better?

Comment: This assumes we are running Windows.